# How are leveling seats chosen in Germany's Bundestag chosen?

Tags: election, germany, proportional-representation

In Germany's Bundestag half the MPs are elected by First Past The Post and the other half are elected from party lists. Before an election parties submit regional lists in every state. The lists are used to achieve proportional representation in every state. Leveling seats are used to achieve proportional representation in the national level.

My question is: Since parties submit only regional lists and no national lists then where are these leveling seats chosen from?

If they are chosen from the regional lists then doesn't that mean that some states will have more MPs than they are entitled to?

Comment: Up to rounding errors, national PR would be the sum of regional PR.

Comment: @o.m., In last German election, 111 leveling seats were added to achieve national PR.

Comment: It's very complex: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberhangmandat#%C3%9Cberhangmandate_im_Bundestagswahlrecht

Comment: “Entitled“ in what sense? By definition, provinces are entitled to exactly as many MPs as this (needlessly complicated patched together) calculation grants them.

Comment: @Relaxed Each state should have seats proportional to its population as in §6 (2) BWahlG. The distribution of seats is done in such a way that this distribution is maintained - if leveling seats are created in one state, other states are assigned more seats as well in order to maintain the proportional distribution.

Comment: @Polygnome That's not *at all* what §6 (2) BWahlG provides. It just describes the calculation. In other words: Each province gets as many seats as it gets, there is no external standard to judge this calculation against.

Comment: @relaxed There is an "external" judge to the BWahlG. The Basic Law lays out how the BWahlG has to look like, that is the basis of the decision of the BVerfG to demand the reform which took place in 2013. Proportional distribution of seats to states is demanded by the constitution (within reason). All votes have to be equal. the vote in state A can not have more weight then the vote in state B ("Gleichheitsgrundsatz"). If the seats were not distributed by population, votes would hold unequal weight and thus the law would be unconstitutional.

Comment: @Polygnome I know all this but it's again a completely different point, you just mix up many different issues without having answered my original comment. Also note that it's actually the opposite: Distributing seats by population (as opposed to votes cast) makes some votes count more than others (namely those in provinces with lower turnout). I still see no basis for provinces as such being “entitled” to anything.

Comment: @Relaxed You have equality of *chance*, not outcome. Equality has to be ex ante - prior to voting - not after. In a system where you have elections by state, seats must be distributed proportional to population to have ex ante equality. If you think the system is unconstitutional, take it up with the BVerG. I happily admit I am not versed enough in constitutional law and the various minutiae to discuss this in depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q:** Since parties submit only regional lists and no national lists then where are these leveling seats chosen from?

Since 2013, there are two types of leveling seats: Überhangsmandate and Ausgleichsmandate.
**Both are chosen from the regional lists (*Landesliste*)**, and seats assigned per state are redistributed accordingly to keep the proportions.

[Wikipedia has its own article describing how seats are chosen (in German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitzzuteilungsverfahren_nach_der_Wahl_zum_Deutschen_Bundestag).

The relevant law is  [§6 Bundeswahlgesetz (BWahlG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bwahlg/__6.html). *Unfortunately, I could not find a **current** translation of the law*.

> ## Bundeswahlgesetz
>
> ### § 6 Wahl nach Landeslisten
>
> - (1) Für die Verteilung der nach **Landeslisten** zu besetzenden Sitze werden die für jede **Landesliste** abgegebenen Zweitstimmen zusammengezählt. Nicht berücksichtigt werden dabei die Zweitstimmen derjenigen Wähler, die ihre Erststimme für einen im Wahlkreis erfolgreichen Bewerber abgegeben haben, der gemäß § 20 Absatz 3 oder von einer Partei vorgeschlagen ist, die nach Absatz 3 bei der Sitzverteilung nicht berücksichtigt wird oder für die in dem betreffenden Land keine **Landesliste** zugelassen ist. Von der Gesamtzahl der Abgeordneten (§ 1 Absatz 1) wird die Zahl der erfolgreichen Wahlkreisbewerber abgezogen, die in Satz 2 genannt sind.
> - (2) In einer ersten Verteilung wird zunächst die Gesamtzahl der Sitze (§ 1 Absatz 1) in dem in Satz 2 bis 7 beschriebenen Berechnungsverfahren den Ländern nach deren Bevölkerungsanteil (§ 3 Absatz 1) und sodann in jedem Land die Zahl der dort nach Absatz 1 Satz 3 verbleibenden Sitze auf der Grundlage der zu berücksichtigenden Zweitstimmen den **Landeslisten** zugeordnet. Jede **Landesliste** erhält so viele Sitze, wie sich nach Teilung der Summe ihrer erhaltenen Zweitstimmen durch einen Zuteilungsdivisor ergeben. Zahlenbruchteile unter 0,5 werden auf die darunter liegende ganze Zahl abgerundet, solche über 0,5 werden auf die darüber liegende ganze Zahl aufgerundet. Zahlenbruchteile, die gleich 0,5 sind, werden so aufgerundet oder abgerundet, dass die Zahl der zu vergebenden Sitze eingehalten wird; ergeben sich dabei mehrere mögliche Sitzzuteilungen, so entscheidet das vom Bundeswahlleiter zu ziehende Los. Der Zuteilungsdivisor ist so zu bestimmen, dass insgesamt so viele Sitze auf die **Landeslisten** entfallen, wie Sitze zu vergeben sind. Dazu wird zunächst die Gesamtzahl der Zweitstimmen aller zu berücksichtigenden **Landeslisten** durch die Zahl der jeweils nach Absatz 1 Satz 3 verbleibenden Sitze geteilt. Entfallen danach mehr Sitze auf die **Landeslisten**, als Sitze zu vergeben sind, ist der Zuteilungsdivisor so heraufzusetzen, dass sich bei der Berechnung die zu vergebende Sitzzahl ergibt; entfallen zu wenig Sitze auf die **Landeslisten**, ist der Zuteilungsdivisor entsprechend herunterzusetzen.
> - (3) Bei Verteilung der Sitze auf die **Landeslisten** werden nur Parteien berücksichtigt, die mindestens 5 Prozent der im Wahlgebiet abgegebenen gültigen Zweitstimmen erhalten oder in mindestens drei Wahlkreisen einen Sitz errungen haben. Satz 1 findet auf die von Parteien nationaler Minderheiten eingereichten Listen keine Anwendung.
> - (4) Von der für jede **Landesliste** so ermittelten Sitzzahl wird die Zahl der von der Partei in den Wahlkreisen des Landes errungenen Sitze (§ 5) abgerechnet. In den Wahlkreisen errungene Sitze verbleiben einer Partei auch dann, wenn sie die nach den Absätzen 2 und 3 ermittelte Zahl übersteigen.
> - (5) Die Zahl der nach Absatz 1 Satz 3 verbleibenden Sitze wird so lange erhöht, bis jede Partei bei der zweiten Verteilung der Sitze nach Absatz 6 Satz 1 mindestens die bei der ersten Verteilung nach den Absätzen 2 und 3 für sie ermittelten zuzüglich der in den Wahlkreisen errungenen Sitze erhält, die nicht nach Absatz 4 Satz 1 von der Zahl der für die **Landesliste** ermittelten Sitze abgerechnet werden können. Die Gesamtzahl der Sitze (§ 1 Absatz 1) erhöht sich um die Unterschiedszahl.
> - (6) Die nach Absatz 5 Satz 1 zu vergebenden Sitze werden in jedem Fall **bundesweit** nach der Zahl der zu berücksichtigenden Zweitstimmen in dem in Absatz 2 Satz 2 bis 7 beschriebenen Berechnungsverfahren auf die nach Absatz 3 zu berücksichtigenden Parteien verteilt. In den Parteien werden die Sitze nach der Zahl der zu berücksichtigenden Zweitstimmen in dem in Absatz 2 Satz 2 bis 7 beschriebenen Berechnungsverfahren auf die **Landeslisten** verteilt; dabei wird jeder **Landesliste** mindestens die Zahl der in den Wahlkreisen des Landes von der Partei errungenen Sitze zugeteilt. Von der für jede **Landesliste** ermittelten Sitzzahl wird die Zahl der von der Partei in den Wahlkreisen des Landes errungenen Sitze (§ 5) abgerechnet. Die restlichen Sitze werden aus der **Landesliste** in der dort festgelegten Reihenfolge besetzt. Bewerber, die in einem Wahlkreis gewählt sind, bleiben auf der **Landesliste** unberücksichtigt. Entfallen auf eine **Landesliste** mehr Sitze, als Bewerber benannt sind, so bleiben diese Sitze unbesetzt.
> - (7) Erhält bei der Verteilung der Sitze nach den Absätzen 2 bis 6 eine Partei, auf die mehr als die Hälfte der Gesamtzahl der Zweitstimmen aller zu berücksichtigenden Parteien entfallen ist, nicht mehr als die Hälfte der Sitze, werden ihr weitere Sitze zugeteilt, bis auf sie ein Sitz mehr als die Hälfte der Sitze entfällt. Die Sitze werden in der Partei entsprechend Absatz 6 Satz 2 bis 6 verteilt. In einem solchen Falle erhöht sich die nach Absatz 5 ermittelte Gesamtzahl der Sitze (§ 1 Absatz 1) um die Unterschiedszahl.

(*highlights are mine*)

The law doesn't specifically call them leveling seats or, but by persusing it you can see that the distribution of those seats is done according to regional lists (Landesliste). §7, which dealt with combined lists, is no longer in force - it has been abolished (see [§7 BWahlG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bwahlg/__7.html)).